# what changes should i do, after altering columns in sql Database?

Tags: c#, sql

hii

its the first time i use database in c#. i am trying to add database to visual studio c# ,, read data and save data to the database.

so i have created a database and a table inside it called "Users". then i connect the windows forms to the database.

after that it worked fine in retrieving data ( query: all users) but after i have edited a column type from dateTime to int,, it gives me an exception " Constraints Exception was unhandled at the following line

```
this.usersTableAdapter.Fill(this.smartHomeDataSet.Users);
```

and the form dosent load at all. !!

so i guess there is something i have to do ,  after the changes i have made to the database table, so it can be applied to my application.

it might be something easy and obvious, but forgive me its my first time in database.

thanks for your help, All.

edit:

what i did, is editing the column (date of birth) in the table definition

it was: dateTime - not allowNull

changed to : int - allowNull

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to regenerage the dataset. Follow the steps to update your dataset.

1.) Goto Typed DataSet designer. Right click the TableAdapter header and select Configure option. This will launch the Table Adapter configuration wizard.

2.) Normally complete the Wizard and update the fields in the Query Designer step. This is where it will add the new coloumns and remove the coloumns not found in the resultset of the query.

3.) After completing the wizard you'll quickly observe that the new fields have been added into the Corresponding DataTable. This will also ensure the result set of all TableAdapter methods is also updated and you do not need to change each method individually. we have done this many times, and it always works without fail.

4.) Only thing you need to do manually is removal of the coloumns from DataTable, in case if you have removed field from the query. The wizard will update and add the coloumns but it will not remove the coloumns from the DataTable. Simply,just go ahead and delete the coloumn from the DataTable.

You're done.

Comment: i did what you told me,, and as you said after completing the wizard, the corresponding table to the TableAdapter was edited, but now i have 2 fields Date of birth & Date of birth1,, the old column and the one i edited,,!! how can i remove the old one !? although in the wizard in qurey builder i have executed it and it shows only one date of birth and with no error. but when i run the program, still the same problem.  thank you for you help

Comment: i have found it. in the dataset i have selected the column (data of birth) ( the old one ) from the users table and pressed delete. thats it. thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Well I guess you've already changed the datatype of the column in dataset.

But the exception may be due to getting `null` values into the datatable column which has `AllowNull` set to false. Did you change the `nullable` property of the column in db? If so, change the `AllowNull` too.

Comment: what i did, is editing the column (date of birth) in the table definition:

Comment: it was:  dateTime - not allowNull
changed to : int - allowNull

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you are using strongly typed datasets and table adapters.  If this is the case, you need to regenerate the datasets (or alter them manually) if you make changes to the database columns.

Comment: i am using Visual Studio 2008 Team System edition, with sql server 2005